# Using tab as indentation in anaconda-mode with spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, python, anaconda-mode

I recently installed spacemacs with the python mode and would like to change the default indentation to be TAB instead of four spaces. 
What I did is I added `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t tab-width 4)` to my just after`(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)` in my `config.el`. Unfortunately, when I open a python file, I can see that indentation is still done with 4 spaces instead of one TAB. Did any of you come across this issue before ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Anaconda-mode](https://github.com/proofit404/anaconda-mode/blob/master/anaconda-mode.el) is a minor-mode which has nothing to do with indentation AFAIK. So I assume that you actually mean `python-mode`.

The second line in `python-mode` is

```
(set (make-local-variable 'indent-tabs-mode) nil)
```

which overrides the default value.

So you must set `indent-tabs-mode` in `python-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

Using `spacemacs` you can add that line to the [function `dotspacemacs/user-config`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/c7a103a772d808101d7635ec10f292ab9202d9ee/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L305) in your [`spacemacs` initialization file](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#dotfile-configuration) -- most likely `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el` or `~/.spacemacs`.

Comment: And the previous line similarly sets `tab-width` to 8.  `python-mode` purposefully makes it difficult, because Python's layout rules mean that it's easy to shoot oneself in the foot.  E.g. the Python *language* defines TABs as occupying 8 columns, so using a `tab-width` different from 8 means that the file will not be displayed in the way that python will interpret it.  It may still work, of course, but: buyer beware.

Comment: @Stefan AFAIK it is no problem if one uses consistently tabs for indentation. Real problems occur if one mixes tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Stefan I tended to `(define-minor-mode indent-tabs-mode "Toggle indent-tabs-mode.")  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'indent-tabs-mode)`. Is there any reason why `indent-tabs-mode` is not defined as a real minor-mode? (If you want I can also ask this as a proper question here on emacs.sx.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am really new on spacemacs could you advise me in which of the function (`python/init-python ` maybe?) I should paste the code you prioovided in your answer

Comment: @RobinNicole I added some text about the installation of the hook in your init-file at the end of the answer.